# putting one code inside another

Tags: javascript, php

i need some help .

this is a code for my php application installation page. while installing php application member can write license key in this .

```
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"licensekey\" value=\"" . licensekey . "\" style=\"width:300px\"></td>
```

but i want that when some write key in above code so the key will be used in below code where i written( the license key here ) . means i want to show blank so members can write key in below code ( the license key here ) . the above code show the blank but i m not able to add it in below code. .

```
$spbas->license_key=' the license key here ';
```

sorry for my very bad english .

and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to display "license key here" in the textbox initially, and then let the user type their key in.

To do that, you can use the following, no PHP is required.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="license key here" />
```

If, however, you want to display a textbox containing some key that's been generated in PHP, its better to do it like so:

```
<?php

//some code...
$license_key = "xxx";
?>

<input type="text" placeholder="license key here" value="<?php echo $license_key; ?>" />

<?php
//some more code...
?>
```

It's not great to echo out HTML with PHP.  Although that works, it makes it VERY easy to make mistakes with quotes and such, so try and avoid it unless it becomes absolutely necessary.  I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
echo "
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"licensekey\" value=\"" . $spbas->license_key . "\" style=\"width:300px\"></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand you right, but you want to save the license key which your customer enters in the input field in the $spbas->license_key attribute?

Then you only need to create a `<form action="PHPSCRIPTHERE" method="POST">` tag around the input field with your php script as target -> action attribute. In your PHP script you can access the license key your user entered over `$_POST['licensekey']`. Then you can assign this to the `$license_key` attribute of your object.